# Can I access global variables in a local function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the variables **name**, **email**, **pass**, but every time I try to do so, **User.NAME**, **User.Email_ID** & **User.PASSWORD** have null value. Shouldn't I be able to use those 3 variables globally?

```
<html>
<head><title>Document</title></head>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
  <input type="text" id="name"><br>
  <input type="email" id="mail"><br>
  <input type="password" id="pass"><br>
  <button onclick="Register()">Register</button>
  <button onclick="Show()">Show in console</button> <br>
  <div id="view" style="background-color: red; color:white; font-family: algerian; text-align: center;"></div>
  <script>
  const student=[];

  var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
  var mail= document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var pass= document.getElementById("pass").value;

  var Register = function() {
      let User=JSON.parse(`{"NAME":"`+name+`", "EMAIL_ID":"`+mail+`", "PASSWORD":"`+pass+`"}`);
      console.log(User);
      student.push(User);
  }

  function Show() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          let n=student.length; 
          var text="";
          for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              text=text+"Name="+student[i].NAME+", Email="+student[i].EMAIL_ID+", Password="+student[i].PASSWORD+"<br>";
          }
          document.getElementById("view").innerHTML=text;
    }, 2000);
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but that `JSON.parse` hurts my eyes! Don't do that. Use object literals. The indentation of your code could be improved...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As to your question: you never call `Register`, so `students` remains an empty array.

Comment: @trincot It is the seperate js file. I actually called that function through a button in HTML

Comment: @SaptarshiDey, please edit your question to make your problem reproducible. This means you should add the code that deals with the button click.

Comment: @trincot I added the whole HTML file for reference. Now I suppose you probably won't have any trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can.

The things that you get wrong is that you assign the value of the inputs too early.

Let's take a look.

```
var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
var mail= document.getElementById("mail").value;
var pass= document.getElementById("pass").value;
```

when the browser parse your code it Immediately assign input value to the variables and it contains empty values at that time.

You want to only reference the input elements at this time like this.

```
var userName= document.getElementById("name"); // note we change the variable from name to userName hence we cannot uses "name" as a variable 
var mail= document.getElementById("mail");
var pass= document.getElementById("pass");
```

and get the value of the element inside register() function.

Try to look at the whole code:

```
const students = [];
    let userName = document.getElementById('name')
    let mail = document.getElementById('mail')
    let pass = document.getElementById('pass')


    function register() {
      let user = { name: userName.value, email_id: mail.value, pass: pass.value };
      console.log(user);
      students.push(user);
    }

    function show() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        let text = '';
        for (const student of students) {
          text = `Name=${student.name}, Email=${student.email_id}, Password=${student.pass} <br>`
        }
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = text;
      }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you grab the input values at page load, and not at the moment the Register button is clicked.

So move those lines into the `Register` function.

I must mentioned that using `JSON.parse` on a self constructed string is an antipattern. You should use a plain old object literal.

Less important, but it is common practice to use camelCase for variables, and reserve PascalCase for constructors/classes. So rename `User` to `user`. The same holds for properties, but I left them like they are, as it impacts your other code:

```
  var Register = function() {
      var name= document.getElementById("name").value;
      var mail= document.getElementById("mail").value;
      var pass= document.getElementById("pass").value;
      let user= { "NAME": name, "EMAIL_ID": mail, "PASSWORD": pass };
      console.log(user);
      student.push(user);
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes ofcourse you can, As a best practice use let keyword instead of var.
You're parsing the json wrongly i guess.

Comment: The code runs perfectly when I declare & initialize the variables within the function itself